# Using the results of the output of one query as table names

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have written the following code which extracts the names of tables which have used storage in Sentinel. I'm not sure if Kusto is capable of doing the query but essentially I want to use the value stored in "Out" as names of tables. e.g union(Out) or search in (Out) *

```
let MyTables = 
Usage 
| where Quantity > 0
| summarize by DataType ;
let Out = 
MyTables
| summarize makelist(DataType);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The tables referenced by the query should be known during query planning. A possible workaround can be generating the query and invoking it using the [execute_query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/execute-query-plugin) plugin.